# Find sum of numbers in jtextfield

Tags: java

I want to get the sum of all numbers from a `JTextField`. I'am using this code but it doesn't work. The problem is that is that I can't get the `{d1}` as numbers from the `JTextField`.

```
String a = jTextField1.getText();
int d1= Integer.parseInt(a);
        int Arry[] = {d1};
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i<Arry.length; i++ )
  {
      sum=sum + Arry[i];
  }  
jTextField2.setText(sum+"");
```

Comment: I cannot see any problem.

Comment: What is the code for your jTextField1?

Comment: @Paulo there are probably spaces in the JTextField

Comment: thanx u for replaying . there is no code for  jTextField1 , and the the probleme is that jTextField2 dosnt give the sum of numbers frome jTextField1 .

Comment: What is in `jTextField1`? A list is integers separated by spaces? Random text you need to scan for digits?

Comment: no . i put numbers in jTextField1 like this 123

Comment: You should probably provide a couple of inputs and desired outputs

Answer (score 0):

If `jTextField1` contains not only numbers, you may want to extract all the digits like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(jTextField1.getText());
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
```

then sum the numbers:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer number : numbers)
        sum += number;
```

Comment: thank you sir you was very helpful ... i just changed list : List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); to    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); and it work .... thank you guys

Comment: Oh, that's great! I just thought you may want to accept this answer as a correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the JTextField will only contain input that can be parsed into ints, e.g. no letters or symbols, then the only possible remaining issue is whitespace between your numbers. I would suggest that you go to the [Pattern API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and look for characters that can detect whitespace and then go to [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and find a method that can split a `String` based on an input regular expression (regex). Then from there you can easily parse the split `String` into `int`s and get your sum. For example:

```
String a = jTextFieldName.getText();
String[] storage = a.someSplittingMethod("whitespace regex");
int sum = 0;
for(int c = 0; c < storage.length; c++)
    sum += Integer.parseInt(storage[c]);
```